# How to make grid elements align their content to the same height

Tags: html, css, grid

I wonder if it is possible to align content in grid items so they are of the same height.
[image]

Is it possible to make all item titles and item texts take the same amount of space as the heightest one?

I tried to achieved this with flexbox but didn't manage to achieve it. Also I thought about making two separate grids: for item titles and item texts, but it turned out to be impossible to make responsive.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-mcclintock-l469n?file=/style.css

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use an outer flex box with a row alignment and an inner flex box with a column alignment. I've created a snippet for you to demonstrate below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.inner{
  flex-direction: column;
  width:33.3333333%;
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-right:15px;
}

.title {
  background-color:lightcoral
}

.body{
      background-color:lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="grid title">
    <div class="inner">
      <h1>Item title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <h1>Item title Item title Item title Item title</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="inner">
      <h1>Item title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid body">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, modi?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, modi?
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetdfdaur adipisicing elit. Ipsa,
          modi? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa,
          modi?
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="inner">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, modi?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```